# Azure Active Directory - Policies

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory

I need to limited sign in for email account for all employs joined in our azure AD ,  Goal: just they can sign in company email in browser , and not use Gmail/etc email .

How to create policy in Azure? I hope is my explanation and goal it is clear.

Please giving advise.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the browser activity from Azure AD.

With Azure AD you can manage identities.

To achieve your goal GPOs and Firewalls rules are your best option